# AttributeError: 'WordList' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, nlp, token, lemmatization, word-list

I am trying to apply Lemmatization after I tokenized my "script" column. But I get an AttributeError. I tried different thins

Here is my "script" column:

```
df_toklem["script"][0:5]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
type(df_toklem["script"])
```

Output:

```
id
1    [ext, street, day, ups, man, big, pot, belly, ...
2    [credits, still, life, tableaus, lawford, n, h...
3    [fade, ext, convent, day, whispering, nuns, pr...
4    [fade, int, c, hercules, turbo, prop, night, e...
5    [open, theme, jaws, plane, busts, clouds, like...
Name: script, dtype: object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pandas.core.series.Series
```

And the code where I try to apply Lemmatization:

```
from textblob import Word
nltk.download("wordnet")
df_toklem["script"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))
```

**ERROR:**

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-dbc80c619ec5> in <module>
      1 from textblob import Word
      2 nltk.download("wordnet")
----> 3 df_toklem["script"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-72-dbc80c619ec5> in <lambda>(x)
      1 from textblob import Word
      2 nltk.download("wordnet")
----> 3 df_toklem["script"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))

AttributeError: 'WordList' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I tried different things but unfortunately couldn't find an efficient solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't work because you are applying a string function (split) to a Word List.
I would try to use `nltk`, instead, and create a new pandas column with my tokenized data:

```
import nltk
df_toklem['tokenized'] = df_toklem.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['script']))
```

Comment: Hmm, I got it. Thank you for the help :) @circuito

Comment: please do not forget to accept/upvote my answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: By the way, you should delete ", axis=1" :) @circuito

Comment: Yeah sorry about that! :p